# How do I get back Longitude and Latitude from another widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

One flutter widget has the GPS coordinates 
I need to pass the coordinates to another widget.

This is the currentLocation widget class. I need the long lat value in another widget.

```
_initCurrentLocation() {
    Geolocator()
      ..forceAndroidLocationManager = !widget.androidFusedLocation
      ..getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
      ).then((position) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() => _currentPosition = position);
        }
      }).catchError((e) {
        //
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<GeolocationStatus>(
        future: Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<GeolocationStatus> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }


return Text('${_currentPosition.latitude} ${_currentPosition.longitude}'),
```

This is the other widget. This widget has a function that needs the long and lat to make an API call.

```
Future loadWeather() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    // final lat = //get the value from other widget;
    // final lon = //get the value from other widget 

    final weatherResponse = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${openWeatherToken}&lat=${lat.toString()}&lon=${lon.toString()}');
```

Comment: Can you show the other widget.